# Center Dropdowns of Bootstrap Navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm afraid I am having my troubles with Bootstrap's navigation. I want to create a navbar with some dropdowns. I want to align the dropdown centrally, right under the navbar items (in the large viewport).

I am not sure how to do this though, i.e. how to center them under the text. Right now they are too far to the left. I could move them to the right manually, by saying `margin-left: 50px;` but that would be too static, and not look good on different viewports etc. I also thought of using flexbox, but it seems to completely change the layout.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhs6Lcgw/

I would like to center the dropdown under the 'Our Company'.

[image]

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/o7qtkmvr/2/

Comment: Yes, but there my nav items are not spread out anymore.

Comment: what do you mean? it's laid out the same way it was before, but the text is horizontally centered now. not sure what you mean by "not spread out anymore"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhs6Lcgw/ - the nav items are spread, with the first and last child of list to the very left and right.

Comment: I also do not want to center the text horizontally, but center the dropdowns underneath the navitems. Right now they are aligned to the left.I think you were a bit too fast and edited the fiddle which I originally posted, but then swapped with the correct one, so that's the misunderstanding here.

Comment: Oh your fiddle has linked resources and CSS now - it was just HTML before. is this what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/Lhs6Lcgw/1/

Comment: I'm not sure. The Pricing Nav + Dropdown look good, but the other dropdown is still very far to the left, not centered under the nav item. Do you know what I mean? I'll add a screenshot to my question.

Comment: this is what it looks like to me in chrome and firefox http://i.imgur.com/CfPAXhR.png it doesn't look like your screenshot

Comment: That's interesting. I am also viewing it in Chrome (and have also tried firefox just now, same) What did you change though? Or did it look like this to you right from the start?

Comment: add `text-align: center;` to the `a` elements, or you can use the `.text-center` helper class in bootstrap on those elements.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I think the reason why you see it centered is because you are viewing it on a small viewport. Try resizing the window, so that it is bigger and the Hamburger Menu disappears. Then when you click on the nav item the dropdown will be disaligned

Comment: ah gotcha, how's this? https://jsfiddle.net/Lhs6Lcgw/3/

Comment: amazing, how did you do this?

Comment: magic! j/k I'll submit an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `text-align: center` to the `a` tags, or use the `.text-center` bootstrap helper class to those elements to center the link horizontally. Then to center the menu itself in desktop view, add a media query that applies `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` since the menu is absolutely positioned relative to the parent in desktop.

```css
.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav li:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav li:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .dropdown-menu {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">

  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Welcome<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown_angebot" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Pricing
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_angebot">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="softwareentwicklung.php">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="qualitaetssicherung.php">Another action</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown_unternehmen" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Our Company
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_unternehmen">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="geschichte.php">History</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="karriere.php">Career</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="klienten.php">Clients</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="anfahrt.php">Get here<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="kontakt.php">Contact<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```